# HTML element moving when viewport width changes, but no change in CSS

Tags: html, css

Having a strange issue which has happened to me before but I couldn't figure out the issue either. I can work around it but I'd prefer to understand why it's happening so that I can fix the root issue.

The position of a  element is changing between 1200px and 1999px as you can see here:
1200px:
[image: Before]
1999px:
[image: After]
The element is behaving like there is a breakpoint at 1200 but there isn't and the css doesn't change either according to Chrome dev tools.
You can see that the margin and position change slightly but not enough to cause such a shift in position.

I am using Bootstrap in case that matters.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Can we get some code, or live example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:
`margin-top: 1.5%`

You have a percentage based margin value, therefore, on resize, the positioning of the `H2` will vary.
If you don't want it to vary, change it to another unit, for example `px`.

Also, you might want to specify offsets properties (left/right, top/bottom) of the element:

> `absolute`
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created
>   for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is positioned relative
>   to its closest positioned ancestor if any; otherwise, it is placed
>   relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is
>   determined by the values of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`. This value
>   creates a new stacking context when the value of `z-index` is not `auto`.
>   Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse
>   with any other margins. [Source MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing to fix it.
Like I said, I knew a workaround I just wanted to understand what is going on.

Thanks a lot for your explaination!